# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax at line 1 INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert a row into a table. Well, the page add the row, but when it does, appears a MySQL error, something like this:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1' at line 1

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$lang = "english";
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require '../security.php';
$con=mysqli_connect($sec[0],$sec[1],$sec[2],$lang);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
} else {
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `ta_exp` (`date`, `cargo`, `DP`, `LP`, `url`)
VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['date_exp'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['cargo_exp'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['lp_exp'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['dp_exp'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['url'])."')");

if (!mysqli_query($con,$result)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I recommend taking the SQL parameter out from `mysqli_query` and assigning it to an intermediate variable `$sql`. Please echo that and edit it into your question - it should be clear from there.

Comment: You _really_ should use a prepared statement and parameter binding instead of all those escape calls. This is a question of most basic application security. It is explained in the documentation of the mysqli extension.

Comment: @user3659034, please only make substantive edits that make questions clearer - changing code formatting (unless it is especially unreadable) is generally regarded as "too minor" or "matter of opinion". There's plenty of questions on Meta Stack Overflow about this topic.

Comment: I know this isn't your issue but in your columns array you have DP and then LP and in your values you have LP and then DP, might want to fix that. Also, I don't think it's the issue, but it's generally unnecessary to put the table name in quotations.

Comment: But I didn't have problems when i used this kind of syntax. But i will tried with "new mysqli()"

Comment: askascha is right, but I don't think that advice is the immediate cause of the problem. The problem is your SQL is malformed, and you need to dig into why. See my advice above.

Comment: For debugging, you really should build the query into a var, e.g. `$sql = "INSERT ..."`, so you can echo out EXACTLY what you built. As it stands now. That'll make it **FAR** easier to figure out the problem.

Comment: Also what does your table structure look like? Are you trying to put text into a number column somewhere?

Comment: Yes, as Marc suggested, building the query as one long string and printing it out will likely make the error obvious. As arkascha suggested, using MySQLi's prepared statements will avoid having to type in all those function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_prepare` is the way to go:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `ta_exp` (`date`, `cargo`, `DP`, `LP`, `url`)
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";          
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query)) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $_GET['date_exp'],
                                           $_GET['cargo_exp'],
                                           $_GET['lp_exp'],
                                           $_GET['dp_exp'],
                                           $_GET['url']);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: I still want to point out that the LP and DP columns seemed to be switched, but in this case, still correct because that is how they were in the original post.

Comment: Well, yeah, i did it, i change emmm all my code to something like:

$con = new mysqli($sec[0],$sec[1],$sec[2],$lang);
if ($con->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $con->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
} else {
}

Comment: @Mark Well, thanks, and yes, whatever I have to do it

Answer (score 0):

Finally my code seems like this:

```
$con = new mysqli($sec[0],$sec[1],$sec[2],$lang);
if ($con->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $con->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
} else {
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO experiences (`date`, `cargo`, `DP`, `LP`, `url`)
VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['date_exp'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['cargo_exp'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['lp_exp'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['dp_exp'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['url'])."')";

if($con->query($sql) === false)
{
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  $last = $con->insert_id;
  $aff = $con->affected_rows;
}

$con->close();
```